# Spring + Hibernate ehcache second level cache

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, ehcache

I am using Spring version 4.1.1 and hibernate version 4.3.7, I am using annotations for mapping with database. Now I want to integrate Hibernate second level cache.

```
<props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>


    </props>
```

I am using Hibernate dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my class file on which I am querying

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assets")
public class Assets {

@Id
@Column(name = "assetID")
private Integer assetID;

@Column(name = "assetName")
private String assetName;
}
```

and the final hibernate query is

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Assets").setCacheable(true).list();
```

Please tell me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure second level cache in your spring configuration file

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

You need to annotate your entity even if you use query cache only because it stocks results in second level cache.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assets")
@Cacheable @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Assets {
....
}
```

You need also to have an xml file to configure cache region (ehcache.xml), here is a default cache region configuration [for more details](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-cfgbasics_xml_configuration.html) :

```
<ehcache>
   <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
   <defaultCache
      maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
      eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="120"
      timeToLiveSeconds="120"
      maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
      diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
      <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
   </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

Update :

This works for me :

```
<!-- EHCache-Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I am including this with Spring framework, It is not recognizing ehcache, So please tell me the jars or XMLNS location for this.